# Prettier auto "correct" regex escaping forward slash `\`

Tags: regex, prettier

`pattern: '^131\.[0-9]{6}$',`

prettier change it to `pattern: '^131.[0-9]{6}$',`. Is there a way to ignore line, or ignore file?

Comment: You can't do this because `.` has a special meaning in regex. You are escaping `.` to strip it of that meaning. So there is no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @TheChetan that is awfully misleading. You can escape special characters in regex to be literal characters. "If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash" - https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#Special_Characters

Comment: @shriek You're right, my understanding back then was incorrect. That comment is wrong and misguiding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming JavaScript (as you're using prettier.)  The `'^131\.[0-9]{6}$'` is just a string, not a regex.  Prettier removes unnecessary escape characters when reformatting.  As `\.` isn't a meaningful escape, it's the same as just having `.` on its own *in string context*.

Your aim is to get `\.` into a regex, which I assume you're going to create using the `new RegExp()` constructor; in that case you want to escape the backslash:

```
pattern: '^131\\.[0-9]{6}$'
```

Comment: If his language of implementing was js, then \ escapes just as well. Not sure about other languages.

Comment: using \ itself does not work. I tried to use [.] and `\\.` , and both worked as expected.

Comment: also `.prettierignore` is an option to ignore certain files. You would add this file just like how you add `.gitignore`.

Comment: My original answer was rushed and poorly worded.  I've reworded for clarity.

Comment: You can just use the literal notation to avoid prettier formatter stripping any slashes:  `const regex = /^\S{8,}$/;  regex.test('some string')`   Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: what about apostrophe escape in a project with `/*eslint quotes: ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": false }]*/`. it seems that the only way for it is to use  `.prettierignore`:  example string: `'check the user\'s comment'` changes to `"check the user's comment"` and  ESLint starts crying.

Comment: @AminBakhtiariFar It's not really relevant to the original question, but I'd suggest you look at using https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier to disable the ESLint rules that conflict with prettier.  (It's common practice to do this.)